# Is there a better way to fill missing index of a series with chaining without using pipe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series, chaining

Let's say I have a dataframe, and after some operations I arrive at an intermediate series:

```
>>> df.groupby(...).some_operation()
1    1
3    2
5    1
7    4
8    5
dtype: int64
```

Now, I want to convert the index into a `RangeIndex` with start=1, stop=9, step=1, like this:

```
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    2.0
4    NaN
5    1.0
6    NaN
7    4.0
8    5.0
dtype: float64
```

One way it can be done is:

```
>>> s = df.groupby(...).some_operation()
>>> s.reindex(range(s.index.min(), s.index.max()+1))
```

But I don't want to store the intermediate series. Another way would be:

```
>>> ( df.groupby(...).some_operation()
        .pipe(lambda x: x.reindex(range(x.index.min(), x.index.max()+1))
    )
```

This works, but wondering if there is something better, something like `interpolate` for index or `asfreq`, but for `RangeIndex`. `reindex` could have been an option, but it doesn't support functions, even if it did, it would be clunky. It seems like there must be a method, because it may be a common thing to do, either I am unaware of such method, or can't think of it, if it exists.

It can be assumed that `df.index` is completely different (let's say `datetime index`) and unlikely to be helpful. One can reindex the series by a `range` object with arbitrarily large number and drop the ending `nan`s, but that would be quite inefficient.

For example:

```
A = np.array([ 3, 15, 12, 14, 15,  1, 14, 18, 11, 16, 10, 12, 14, 15, 10, 13, 12,
       11,  6, 13])
B = np.array([1.1 , 1.09, 0.8 , 0.71, 0.37, 0.93, 0.9 , 0.54, 1.29, 0.33, 1.29,
       0.39, 0.69, 0.89, 0.89, 0.46, 1.12, 0.29, 0.61, 0.81])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B})

# This gives:
>>> df.groupby(df['B'].ge(1).cumsum()).size().value_counts(sort=False)
1    1
2    1
4    1
6    1
7    1
dtype: int64
```

How do I make it like below, in a better way than above mentioned methods:

```
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    NaN
4    1.0
5    NaN
6    1.0
7    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: reindex also  supports the range builtin, something like `df.groupby(....).some_operation().reindex(range(df.index.max()+1))` ths can be applied for a range index.

Comment: @anky Yes, but as I said, let's say `df.shape[0]==1k` or `df.index` is `datetime`, and my groups are only a few, like in the question, `df.index.max()+1` seems inefficient. The problem is I want the max for that intermediate series' index, not the entire df.

Comment: can you change the problem to using a datatime index then you can use asfreq('d') to fill in the missing dates